# Watir: How do I execute a JS function which is called through onload through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, iframe, watir

The goal is to have Watir click a button that functions purely through JS.

The main page has an iframe that looks similar to this:

`<iframe name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" src="form1.html" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" height="0" width="100%"></iframe>`

form1.html calls a JS function with onload within the body similar to:

`<body onload="submit();" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="formx">`

Which then presents a button to me with a value/id I can use. I just can't figure out how to click that button through the iframe and onload.

I've tried using frame() and fire_event() and sourcing it directly without success. I'm new to Watir and ruby so perhaps their is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Watir does not care if the button is created by JavaScript or not. If it is displayed on the page, it can click it.

Use Firebug (or similar tool) to inspect the button, it should look like similar to this:

```
<input type="button" id="click_me">
```

or this:

```
<button id="click_me">
```

and you can click it with:

```
browser.button(:id => "click_me").click
```

Since the button is in frame, you have to specify it:

```
browser.frame(:id => "uploadfile").button(:id => "click_me").click
```

Comment: This was the path I was taking originally. The problem is it looks as if Watir can't see the button directly through the frame. The iframe points to another file that fires a JS function when it onloads with a form, which then points to the button. Firebug has no problem locating the button and its id but it seems there are several layers I have to go through.

Comment: You might be confusing 'layers' with 'time'  see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate the onload, you might need to have you script sleep for a second or so in order to give the client side code time to do it's thing. That or use some of the techniques described on the [How to Wait With Watir page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+to+wait+with+Watir) to wait for the button to exist.

You should not need to fire the 'onload' event as far as I know the browser itself would do that as it loads the HTML for the frame, the only detail would be providing enough time for the client side code to have done its thing before trying to make use of any elements that are created by that code.

Otherwise the only 'trick' to addressing the button would be to properly locate and identify it within the DOM.   If the button is created inside the iframe, then as indicated in Zeljko's response you will need to use something along the lines of

```
browser.frame(:id => "uploadfile").button(:id => "click_me").click
```

I recommend using IRB as the way to develop your scripts since you can test out individual commands one at a time and see what works.   it's a lot like being able to step through stuff in a debugger, just a tiny bit more manual.

Comment: Thanks Chuck. I started using IRB to test the commands out individually and saw that it is indeed loading the HTML for the frame. So I used something like browser.frame(:id, "uploadfile").button(:value, "Upload File").click. I see the button even light up when I do this but somehow it isn't actually executing. Perhaps it has something to do with the HTML. It uses an input class with a type button but following immediately after is type file. When I use firebug and highlight the button it actually points to the file type and id and not the button itself. Confusing.

Comment: Ugh. I even tried browser.frame(:id => "uploadfile").button(:class => "ui_button").click and it just highlights the button for a second and nothing else.

Comment: well if you see if flash that's a good indication that Watir tried to click it.  but if nothing is happening, then it might be that the client side javascript is looking for some specific event and a simple .click was not good enough for it.  Look closely at the code for that button and see if there's some kind of event like buttonup specified on that element  you may need to use.fireEvent to fire the specific event the code is looking for.  Or post the code for the elements in that area as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the main window from the iframe? If so, try using the `top` object in JavaScript.

`top.document.getElementById("your_button").doSomething()`